# can we create custom shape and wrap elements into that?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need help for one module in my project, I need to draw shape like square, circle something like that, and need to wrap object in that, Is there any jquery for that ? Or is there anyone have example for that ?

Comment: Please provide some code and your attempts to solve that.

Comment: Provide [mcve].